# execute callback after jquery each iteration

Tags: jquery, callback, each

How can I properly execute the function f when the each iteration has finished so I can count the elements with that particular class?

This gives 0 instead of 16;

```
f = check_hfouten();
$.each(rest, function(idx, val,f) { 
  //alert(idx + ': ' + val); 
  $('td.info.'+idx).children('span').addClass('fout').attr('title',val).end().parent('tr').find('input').addClass('overlayed').click(function(){$(this).removeClass('overlayed')});
    $('.tag_cloud.'+idx).addClass('reminder');
}).function(f);
```

thanks in adv Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the call to `f()` in the body of the `each()` callback:

```
$.each(rest, function(idx, val,f) { 
    //alert(idx + ': ' + val); 
    // -Snip-
    $('.tag_cloud.'+idx).addClass('reminder');
    f();
});
```

Comment: maybe,I should do this, because if I place it outside the each, it is faster then the each.

Comment: If you place it outside the each, `f()` gets called once. If you place it within, `f()` is called for each selected element. Which do you want?

Comment: outside it runs faster then the each, that's the problem

Comment: So each does have a callback! I placed the call to f inside like you said and changed the code in f so it is not redundant anymore, thanks @George

Answer (score 6):

`each` is not asynchronous so you don't need a callback.  Just call it in sequence:

```
f = check_hfouten();

$.each(rest, function(idx, val) { 
  //alert(idx + ': ' + val); 
  $('td.info.'+idx).children('span').addClass('fout').attr('title',val).end().parent('tr').find('input').addClass('overlayed').click(function(){$(this).removeClass('overlayed')});
    $('.tag_cloud.'+idx).addClass('reminder');
});

f();
```

Comment: I hope it is that simple, they are both executed within an ajax function

Comment: If all of this code is placed within the success/complete function of a single ajax call, this should be fine.  If you have multiple ajax calls then you may want to update your question with those details

Comment: it runs faster then the each!

Answer (score 1):

```
group = $("p")
$.each(group, function(idx, val,f) { 
  alert(idx + ': ' + val); 
  if(idx == group.length - 1)
      alert("done");
});
```

The messy way :P

http://jsfiddle.net/cwDjL/