# jquery callback after each() iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, visible

```
 $.each(mappings, function(key, item) {
        if (match(selected_values, item)) {
          $(key).show("slow");
        } else {
          $(key).hide("slow");
        }
    });

    //At this point, all items are still visible!
    var item_count = $('.item').filter(':visible').length;
    if (item_count < 12) { 
        $('.item').not(':visible').slice(0,12 - item_count).show();
    }
```

I am iterating over a data structure, and depending on some selected attributes, some items are hidden, other shown.

Trouble is, the client requests a minimum items visible. So even if the filtering works correctly, and I get a number of 3 visible items, they should  be padded up with 9 more elements, so that at least always 12 are shown.

Now, after the each iteration, it appears that the `.show()` and `.hide()` functions don't have terminated yet. How and where can I apply the padding functions correctly?

I've checked
[Invoking a jQuery function after .each() has completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358205/invoking-a-jquery-function-after-each-has-completed) but his applies the function after each `.show()` or `.hide()`, which is not what I want (it's not ok to pad up during iteration, we first need to hide all which do not apply).

This one:
[execute callback after jquery each iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001388/execute-callback-after-jquery-each-iteration)
doesn't work, when the function is called I have the same problem (show() and hide() haven't completed).

**EDIT**:
I just found out that removing the "slow" attribute in the `.show()` and `.hide()` methods solves the problem. Now, what if I'd like to keep the animations?

Comment: Yeah, I just found out and edited my question. It's the animations. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's synchronous, so you shouldn't need a callback, but you have asynchronous animations, and that's the real issue. Just use a counter in the loop instead of checking the elements length, or add a class :

```
$.each(mappings, function(key, item) {
    if (match(selected_values, item)) {
      $(key).addClass('selected').show("slow");
    } else {
      $(key).hide("slow");
    }
});

if ($('.item.selected').length < 12) { 
    $('.item').not('.selected').slice(0,12 - item_count).show();
}
```

Comment: I like the adding the class solution,. should be faster than filtering for visible ones (?). Of course I also had to add a correspondent removeClass before any of the filtering starts again.

Answer (score 0):

You might get good results by just adding [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to the chain:

```
$('.item').not(':visible').slice(0,12 - item_count).stop().show();
```

Any previously initiated animation (show/hide) will be halted, and the item will just be shown.